# Is there an algorithm that changes LAPACK permutation to a real permutation?

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, matlab, lapack

I realized that `ipiv` argument in LAPACK (like in `dgetrf`) is not a permutation vector (like in matlab). It is a swap permutation.

It is discussed here:
https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-math-kernel-library/topic/290955

another example:

```
A = [ 1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 0] %matlab notation
```

if you run

```
dgetrf_ (&m, &n, A, &lda, ipiv, &info); // C/C++ code
```

the inverse permutation you have is:

```
ipiv = [ 3 3 3]
```

If you want to show it as a matlab inverse permutation it is: `[3 1 2]`

My question is: is there any (inplace) code/algorithm to change ipiv to a permutation? I am writing the code in C.While BLAS is commonly used, I guess someone might have such a code. My matrices can be really large and I want good solutions regarding both times and memory.

Note: One obvious solution is to initialize a vector `p = [1:3]` and swap in `n` iterations. (i.e. swap 1st element with 3rd, swap 2nd element with 3rd, swap 3rd element with 3rd)

Comment: We are not a coding service. And and algorithm is language-agnostic.

Comment: Take a look at lines 247-254 of [dgetri()](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/df/da4/dgetri_8f_source.html) of LAPACK, where the swaping is performed. It is exactly done as it is described in your note. The obivious solution seems to be the good one, likely because computing the PLU decomposition of a matrix is much more complex than applying the permution. If you want to swap the lines of the matrix, `memcpy()` and a buffer of the size of a line may be more efficient than doing for j; temp=a[i*n+j]; a[i*n+j]=a[ib*n+j];a[ib*n+j]=temp;

Comment: In your example the correct permutation is [3, 1, 2] by the way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I implemented it in C. 
I think it is good to have a piece of code that people may need:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) tmpPinv[i] = i;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        int tmp;
        // swap (tmpPinv [ipiv [i]], tmpPinv[i] ) and it is off by one          
        tmp = tmpPinv [ipiv [i]-1];            
        tmpPinv [ipiv [i]-1] = tmpPinv [i];
        tmpPinv [i] = tmp;
    }
```

It is not inplace and it is so sequential; I may need to implement LU decomposition myself.So I won't put a lot of effort to fix this.